# Loop that prompts user until valid input

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

Question: How to continuously prompt user when age is invalid (below 0 above 200, or not-a-number)?

```
var userAge = prompt("Please enter your age");
while (isNaN(userAge)){
    alert("That's not a number, please retry.");
    var userAge = prompt("Please re-enter your age.");
}

if (userAge == 0){
    alert("So you're a baby!");
}
while( userAge < 0  || userAge >= 200){
    alert("I think you may be lying about your age.");
    var userAge = prompt("Please re-enter your age, don't lie this time.");
    {continue}
}

if (userAge > 0 || userAge < 200){
    alert("That's a good age."); 
}

</script>
```

Comment: so what is the problem with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return from while loop with `break` statement. For example:

```
var userAge = prompt("Please enter your age");
while (true) {
    if (isNaN(userAge)) {
        alert("That's not a number, please retry.");
    } else if (userAge < 0 || userAge >= 200) {
        alert("I think you may be lying about your age.");
    } else {
        break;
    }
    var userAge = prompt("Please re-enter your age.");
}
if (userAge == 0) {
    alert("So you're a baby!");
} else {
    alert("That's a good age.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  When userAge = 0 why does the alert "So you're a baby" and "That's a good age." appear?

Comment: @fasteddie only one of these alerts appears

Comment: You're right, thanks again.